# FancyUpload to different folders

Tags: php, ajax, file-upload, upload, fancyupload

I got a plugin online(fancyupload), trying to upload multiple file to different folders. first I created the folders using mkdir() then passed the folder name to a session id both in the index.php file as well as the script.php file, but I discovered the script.php file doesn't see the session and it uploads the files directly to the uploadedfiles folder. can anyone help as I have tried everything possible. I am new to stackoverflow( although been reading on issues here for a while) so really don't know the rules here.

Thank you in advance

```
index.php

<?php
 session_start();
 mkdir("C:/softwares/wamp/www/Emma/uploadedfiles/".$_POST['directory']."/");
$_SESSION['directory'] = $_POST['directory'];
```

Script.php

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photoupload']['tmp_name'], "uploadedfiles/".$_SESSION['directory']."/".$_FILES['photoupload']['name']);
chmod("uploadedfiles/".$_SESSION['directory']."/".$_FILES['photoupload']['name'], 0777);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the question, I have solved the problem, it was quite easy was just thinking in one direction!!!  Thanks anyways viewers